# Synchronization in distributed processes

Tags: synchronization, distributed-computing, distributed-system

"Synchronization is essential for the distributed processes to overcome the limited observation of the system state from the viewpoint of any one process." What does this statement mean ?

Comment: Whatever it means it's not a Stack Overflow question. Maybe it's better directed at the [CS Site](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks. Will post there

Comment: A set of autonomous monolythic applications does not operate any synchronisation ( each local agent takes no other care but just about it's own local states and orchestrates it's own state-transitions ). Result is a set of absolutely isolated local-state transitions. Distributed-computing is the very opposite eco-system, using a mezzo-sphere of carefully crafted system-wide interactions, right due to using a distributed-architecture to get out of local caves of individual agents and create a new "global" eco-system-wide behaviour.